# Can you change the name of a flash drive on the boot menu?

Tags: usb, boot, usb-flash-drive

I have two Staples brand Flash Drives. They work fine and they boot okay, but they have the same name on the boot menu, so when I have them both in the computer, I can't tell which one is the one I want to boot into. One has Ubuntu on it, the other BackTrack 5.

However, the name of those drives show up different on different BIOS. What parameters affect what name shows up for a boot device and how do I change it?

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, the name that would show up is based on the hardware. I also believe, without extensive hardware knowledge, that this is fairly difficult to change. I'll continue looking and update if I see anything helpful.

Comment: You didn't find anything then?